# CodeIgniter headers already sent error with different Server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Code Ignitor 1.7.2 application which runs on a Windows 7 Apache Server. I copied the Application to Windows Pro SP2 Apache Server. Than I am getting the error

**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 0**

I again copied the application another Windows 7 PC and it is working.  Usually this error comes if any space issue.

Please help how to solve this error.

Comment: I'm guessing this could be an easy fix - check character encoding, make sure the file is saved as UTF-8 *without* the BOM and make sure you have no hidden characters or spaces or anything in the file mentioned (at its beginning)

Comment: You probably have a rogue 'echo' or some kind of output happening before codeigniter's output class finally sends the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I found the Bug. I am using a function to detect the MAC address of the system where I am using ob_start() and ob_clean(). This  is causing the error.

Thanks and solved the issue to find the mac address without using those methods.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

please check whether you have 'echo'ed content the redirection page or diplayer any content in the redirection page

Comment: If echo issue why is it working in Windows 7 Apache deplyed machine and not in Windows XP machine.

Comment: Have you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php