# Codeigniter: Message: Cannot modify header error

Tags: php, codeigniter

**This type of question is already asked before**

[Codeigniter: headers already sent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115430/codeigniter-headers-already-sent-error)

[CodeIgniter headers already sent error with different Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293909/codeigniter-headers-already-sent-error-with-different-server)

[Codeigniter - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769209/codeigniter-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

[Codeigniter: Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974891/codeigniter-message-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/69280/#468283

[Codeigniter: Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974891/codeigniter-message-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

**Exact Error I am Getting**

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/hanomart/public_html/ClickMyStay/application/controllers/welcome.php:472)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 675
```

What i am doing at **welcome.php:472 Line**

I am changing a session value like as below

```
$value="Some Value";
$session_data=array("hotel_search_value" => $value);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

**I have tried in below ways.**

1. Checked White spaces  `before <?php and after ?>` (Everything is fine.No white spaces).
2. Changed **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** to **$this->server('remote_addr')** in line system/core/Input.php Line no **351**

But those things didnt solve my problem.

Can anyone help me out in this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Sree ram

Comment: are you echoing or vardumping anything before line 472? (even `$this->load->view('')` counts)

Comment: Oh...!!!! Yes. I kept that for testing. Will it create problem.?

Comment: Turn it off and there shouldnt be that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off all `echo()`ing and `var_dump()`ing before line 472.

Headers are sent whenever is something `echo()`ed out so session library can **not** modify sessions in that point and it triggers error.